# Can I breed more Lilies of the Valley Plant in Animal Crossing New Horizion?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I recently discovered that I have Lilies of the Valley plants that sprung up around the edges of my island. Am I able to combine four of these lilies in a diamond formation to breed more lilies plants?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, lillies of the valley (not to be mistaken with normal lillies) cannot be bred or cloned. There is only one variety (white) which has a chance to appear each day your island is a 5 star island, according to Isabelle's island eval. If your star ranking drops back below 5 stars, it will stop having a chance to appear daily on your island's cliffs. Many sources support this, including:

*...it cannot be bought as a seed, nor can it be bred using hybrid flowers. Instead, this flower only appears and blooms once you have achieved a perfect 5 star island eval rating for your town.*

Nookipedia also confirms that breeding them together to create more does not work, as they do not breed with other nearby lillies of the valley:

*The plant does not breed when placed next to other lilies of the valley, but increases the chance for hybrid flowers if placed nearby other plants.*

Sources:
https://www.ign.com/wikis/animal-crossing-new-horizons/Flower_Guide_-_Hybrid_Flowers,_Flower_Crossbreeding_List#How_to_Get_a_Lily_of_the_Valley

https://nookipedia.com/wiki/Lily_of_the_Valley

Comment: Given how plant genetics work, "increased chance for hybrid flowers" makes no sense at all. Given that the wiki entry does not cite that, I am disinclined to believe that is a thing.